# Dynamic memory access violation in C

Tags: c

i am trying to write a snake game in Code::Blocks and using dynamic memory methods. I can compile and run my game on my pc but no one else that I sent the source code can run the program and they are getting return message that I add here.
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OK7qd.jpg)

And here is my code for if anyone wants to check and determine the problem

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int k,l,j,x,y,n,m;
int midPx,midPy;

void gotoxy(int x,int y){

COORD CRD;
CRD.X=x;
CRD.Y=y;
SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),CRD);
}

int border(int n,int m)
{
gotoxy(10,5);
for(j=0; j<2*n; j++)
     printf("\u2588");

gotoxy(10,5+m);
for(j=0; j<=2*n; j++)
    printf("\u2588");

for(j=0; j<m ; j++)
{
    gotoxy(10,5+j);
    printf("\u2588");

    gotoxy(10+2*n,5+j);
    printf("\u2588");
}
midPx=10+n;
midPy=5+m/2;
x=n;
y=m;
return midPx,midPy,n,m;

}


void randBait()
{
srand(time());
k=11+rand()%31;
l=6+rand()%15;

}


int main()
{
system("chcp 65001");
system("cls");

int *tailRow;
int *tailColumn;
tailRow=malloc(1*sizeof(int));
tailColumn=malloc(1*sizeof(int));

int menu,borderx,bordery;
int mapSize,exitButton;
int sleepTime=0;
int difficulty;
int devam=1;

randBait();

unsigned char tus;

while(devam==1)
{
int continuity=1;
int score=0;
int dy=0,dx=0,tailLen=0;
system("cls");

printf("<<<<< WELCOME TO THE SNAKE GAME! >>>>>\n\n");
printf("-------------------------------\n");
printf("1. Start a New Game\n");
printf("2. Load Previously Saved Game\n");
printf("3. Configure Game Options\n");
printf("4. Exit\n");
printf("-------------------------------\n");
printf("Enter your choice:");

scanf("%d",&menu);

    switch(menu)
    {

        case 1:

            system("cls");
            if(sleepTime==0)
                {
                printf("Please configure the game options first!");
                continuity=0;
                getch();
                break;
                }

            border(borderx,bordery);

            do
            {
                if(kbhit())
                {
                    tus=getch();

                    if(tus==224)
                    {
                        tus=getch();
                        switch(tus)
                        {
                            case 72: dy=-1,dx=0;
                                break;
                            case 80: dy=1,dx=0;
                                break;
                            case 75: dy=0,dx=-1;
                                break;
                            case 77: dy=0,dx=1;

                        }
                    }

                    if(tus==109)
                    {
                        gotoxy(0,0);
                        printf("------------------------------------------------\n");
                        printf("Are you sure you want to exit to the Main Menu?\n");
                        printf("1. YES\n");
                        printf("2. NO\n");
                        //printf("%d",continuity);

                        scanf("%d",&exitButton);
                        switch(exitButton)
                        {
                            case 1:
                                continuity=0;
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                system("cls");
                                border(borderx,bordery);
                                break;

                        }





                    }
                }

                midPx=midPx+dx;
                midPy=midPy+dy;

                if(midPx>=10+(2*x))
                {
                    continuity=0;
                    gotoxy(midPx,midPy);
                    printf(">>>>>GAME OVER<<<<<");
                    getch();
                }

                if(midPx<=10)
                {
                    continuity=0;
                    gotoxy(midPx,midPy);
                    printf(">>>>>GAME OVER<<<<<");
                    getch();
                }

                if(midPy>=5+j){
                    continuity=0;
                    gotoxy(midPx,midPy);
                    printf(">>>>>GAME OVER<<<<<");
                    getch();
                }

                if(midPy<=5)
                {
                    continuity=0;
                    gotoxy(midPx,midPy);
                    printf(">>>>>GAME OVER<<<<<");
                    getch();
                }

                tailRow[0]=midPx;
                tailColumn[0]=midPy;
                int i;

                for(i=1; i<=tailLen; i++)
                {
                    if(midPx==tailRow[i] && midPy==tailColumn[i])
                    {
                        gotoxy(midPx,midPy);
                        printf(">>>>>GAME OVER<<<<<");
                        continuity=0;
                        getch();


                    }


                }


                for(i=0; i<=tailLen; i++)
                {
                    gotoxy(tailRow[i],tailColumn[i]);
                    printf("*");
                }

                if(dx==0)
                {
                    switch(dy)
                    {
                        case  1:
                            gotoxy(midPx,midPy);printf("\u2B9F");
                            break;
                        case -1:
                            gotoxy(midPx,midPy);printf("\u2B9D");
                            break;
                    }
                }

                if(dy==0)
                {
                    switch(dx)
                    {
                        case  1:
                            gotoxy(midPx,midPy);printf("\u2B9E");
                            break;
                        case -1:
                            gotoxy(midPx,midPy);printf("\u2B9C");
                            break;

                    }
                }

                if(midPx==k && midPy==l)
                {
                    randBait();
                    tailLen++;
                    score+=10;

                }
                gotoxy(10+2*x-4,4);
                printf("Score:%d %d %d ",score,midPx,midPy);

                gotoxy(k,l);printf("O");


                Sleep(sleepTime);
                gotoxy(midPx,midPy);printf(" ");

                for(i=0; i<=tailLen; i++){
                    gotoxy(tailRow[i],tailColumn[i]);
                    printf(" ");
                }

                for(i=tailLen; i>0; i--){
                    tailRow[i]=tailRow[i-1];
                    tailColumn[i]=tailColumn[i-1];

                }


                tailRow=realloc(tailRow,sizeof(int)*(tailLen+2));
                tailColumn=realloc(tailColumn,sizeof(int)*(tailLen+2));


            } while(continuity==1);

        case 2:
        {
        break;
        }


        case 3:
            system("cls");
            printf("-------------------\n");
            printf("Game difficulty:\n");
            printf("1. Easy\n");
            printf("2. Normal\n");
            printf("3. Hard\n");
            printf("4. Insane\n");
            printf("-------------------\n");
            printf("Enter your choice:");
            scanf("%d",&difficulty);

            switch(difficulty)
            {
                case 1:
                    sleepTime=400;
                    system("cls");
                    break;

                case 2:
                    sleepTime=240;
                    system("cls");
                    break;

                case 3:
                    sleepTime=120;
                    system("cls");
                    break;

                case 4:
                    sleepTime=60;
                    system("cls");
                    break;
            }

            printf("-------------------\n");
            printf("Choose map size:\n");
            printf("1. Small (16x16)\n");
            printf("2. Medium (32x32)\n");
            printf("3. Large (64x64)\n");
            printf("-------------------\n");
            printf("Enter your choice:");
            scanf("%d",&mapSize);

            switch(mapSize)
            {
                case 1:
                    system("cls");
                    borderx=16;
                    bordery=16;
                    break;

                case 2:
                    system("cls");
                    borderx=32;
                    bordery=32;
                    break;

                case 3:
                    system("cls");
                    borderx=64;
                    bordery=64;
                    break;
            }
            break;




        case 4:
        {
        system("cls");
        printf("<<< THANKS FOR PLAYING THE GAME >>>");
        devam=0;

        }





       }
}
    free(tailColumn);
    free(tailRow);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When looping over an array of `tailLen` elements use `for (int i=0 ; i<tailLen ; i++)`. Not `i<=tailLen` as that moves past the end of the data. Also allocating the `tailRow` and `tailColumn` arrays is inconsistent, as `tailLen` is updated and then the array accessed _before_ its size is adjusted. And why add 2 extra spots in realloc but only one the first time?

Comment: it has to be used with equality sign, and I tried to initialize the malloc with 1 value and increase it at the end of the loop but still doesn't run on other computers

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that this code is in the wrong order:

```
/*USE*/
                for(i=tailLen; i>0; i--){
                    tailRow[i]=tailRow[i-1];
                    tailColumn[i]=tailColumn[i-1];
                }
/*ALLOC*/
                tailRow=realloc(tailRow,sizeof(int)*(tailLen+2));
                tailColumn=realloc(tailColumn,sizeof(int)*(tailLen+2));
```

The first time through, you only have 1 entry in `tailRow`,`tailColumn`, but you are likely to exceed it.

Tailrow/tailColumn is initialized as:

```
tailRow=malloc(1*sizeof(int));
tailColumn=malloc(1*sizeof(int));
```

So another option would be to increase this initial allocation to handle the projected growth before reallocation.

Comment: i tried to change order of blocks and increase the initializer malloc size but it is not worked at all. Still running in my pc but still gives the returned process 0xc0000005 error on other computers.

Comment: One thing you may want to check is the ranges for `setconsolecursorposition` - as per: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolecursorposition it will attempt to move the console window if you are out of range.